# Angular Flex & Material: hide button attribute based on size of screen

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

Is it possible to show / hide certain attributes of a `<button>` tag depending on the screen size with Angular Flex & Material?

Something like this (does not work unfortunately):

```
 <button [fxFlex.lg]="'mat-raised-button'"
         [fxFlex.md]="'mat-icon-button'"
        (click)="new()">
    ...
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my first answer, this one is to tell you that there's no way of applying a directive conditonnaly on templates only using fxFlex.

Suited to your issue however, is the fact that the fxFlex library has an `ngClass` extension, which allows you to apply classes to elements.

[In this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ckkjfh?file=src/app/app.component.ts), you can see it working. All you have to do is apply the correct classes (coming from the material library) to make it work.

Although not optimal, it does the job. I still would recommend using either two buttons, which is cleaner in terms of library use.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know material or what fxFlex is doing. But if you wont get any other help you could use pure css or scss

```
<button [fxFlex]="'mat-raised-button'" id="button1" (click)="new()">...</button>
<button [fxFlex]="'mat-icon-button'" id="button2" (click)="new()">...</button>
```

and

```
@media (min-width: 1000px) { //lg 
    #button2 {
      display:none;
    }
}
 @media (max-width: 1000px) { //md 
    #button1{
      display:none;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the main point was doing it with flex + material. I know how to do it with pure CSS :)

Comment: what does fxFlex do? Could it be doing display:flex? justifying the buttons?

Comment: Not totally. It's also doing that CSS you wrote above :)

Answer (score 1):

The flex-layout library has a [responsive documentation](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Responsive-API), in which you will find those attributes :

```
[fxHide.md]
[fxShow.md]
```

And so on.

You can use them to show/hide elements based on the breakpoints defined by the library; or create your own breakpoints if you need to.

**[Here is an example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gdmgvs)** and the related code :

```
<button [fxHide.xs]="true" [fxHide.md]="true">I'm only displayed on small screen width !</button>
```

Comment: I'm aware of this, but this would make me create x2 amount of buttons. I just want to do it within 1 button and change its styling dynamically.

Comment: @DenissM.no it doesn't make you create two buttons. You can put as many attributes as you want on a single HTML tag.

Comment: can you please provide an example?

Comment: [Here it is](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gdmgvs), resize the panel to see it work

Comment: @DenissM. (forgot to mention your name, sorry)

Comment: You're still hiding the whole button :). What I need to do: I have a button and I want to show `mat-raised-button` attribute only in `lg` and in `md` I want to show `mat-icon-button` attribute. How would you do it?

Comment: @DenissM.ooooooh my bad I didn't read it properly. I'm working on it, notifying you once it's done !